# EKS subnets running out of IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-security-group

So, I have an interesting issue...

Private subnets for an EKS cluster have run out of IPs.. there aren't enough addresses in the subnets to allow the cluster to fully 'keep warm' all of the IPs it can use, so the subnets read '0 Free' in the AWS Console.. but clearly some are free in the cluster because the issue is intermittent (but becoming more problematic).

The current node groups are unmanaged, the cluster can't be rebuilt.

I created new subnets, and created a managed node group... then when I check the nodes, they can't resolve DNS. They can ping IPs but not resolve DNS..

The obvious answer is a missing rule in the SG.. but; the unmanaged nodes have a custom SG which a bunch of rules for cross VPC comms etc. I know we can't add a custom SG to a managed nodegroup... so I thought, perhaps I'd replicate the custom SG onto the SG the managed nodegroup is using (the EKS managed SG which is used for backplane and manage node groups).

This did not resolve the problem.

My questions are mainly... should this work? If the SG isn't stopping DNS from working, then what is? (I've spun up a busybox pod on a node in the node group and checked nslookup.. the correct DNS server is there, but no resolution).

I read that AWS are working on a solution to adding a custom SG to a managed nodegroup, but it's not yet possible.

Comment: The reason for high IP usage is that the aws CNI assigns a VPC address to every pod. It's technically possible to use a different CNI, but not supported: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alternate-cni-plugins.html. "the cluster can't be rebuilt" sounds like a major operational issue beyond your current problem.

Comment: Yeah, the cluster not being rebuilt thing is in progress. I'm really looking for a quick fix to tide us over.. but having trouble getting the nodes in the new node group to work properly.